# Python update scrolledtxt in other module

Tags: python, tkinter

My code is splited to 2modules. one is sub(GUI-tkinter) module and the other is main(main function module).

### sub module(GUI)

```
import main

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import scrolledtext


class GUI():
def __init__(self, master):
   
    # create Window and widgets ...
   
    self.bt_gen = tk.Button(master, text="Generation", command=lambda: self.runGenCode())
    self.bt_gen.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nsew')  # button : generation

def setScrollTxt(self, text):
    self.txt_status.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
    self.txt_status.see(tk.END)

def clearScrollTxt(self):
    self.txt_status.delete('1.0', tk.END)

def runGenCode(self):
    main(self, self.dir_input, self.dir_output)
    self.setScrollTxt("\nCode Generated Successfully!!!\n")



root = tk.Tk()                                                      # create window

app = GUI(root)                                                     # create object

root.mainloop()
```

### main module(main function)

```
def main(self, input, output):

    # function : import data from excel

    self.setScrollTxt("1/4. Import Data : Done!\n")
 
    # function : pre-process data 

    self.setScrollTxt("2/4. Data Pre-Process : Done!\n")


    with open(filename_output + ".h", "w") as fo:                      

    # function : write file

    self.setScrollTxt("3/4. Export Data to .h file : Done!\n")


    with open(filename_output + ".c", "w") as fo:

    # function : write file
    
    self.setScrollTxt("4/4. Export Data to .c file : Done!\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is my code(simple version)

and my problem is scrolledtxt is not updated in 'main' function.
after each step is finished, function 'setScrollTxt' is called in 'main' module. but scrolledtxt is not changed.
Only after finishing 'main' module and executing 'root.mainloop', scrolledtxt is updated.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: first of I suggest using `snake_case` for both variables and function names (`CapitalCase` for classes). also could You show code from main?

Comment: I added main module. this module read data from excel, process, write to c/h file. this takes long time.

Comment: I actually had a similar question and my answer to that was that as far as I know generally imports are used to import functions rather than running themselves. what I mean is that for example main process can be handled by multiple files but it all comes to one file running all of the functions however it is possible that one subfile uses another's imports to use for some sort of definiton of function which then is run by the main file, so at the end that one function is never called in the main file but a function that is called in the main file contains it

Comment: so basically I suggest You import what You need from one file(subfile) to the other (main) since that is usually the order but not that You have to follow it, then run those functions in one file